# isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications returns false even registration succeed

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

### Problem

```
isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
```

return **false** even i successfully received device token.

### Situation

#### 1. Register

After a user has installed my app and at a specific point, I check `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` and if false, I use the code above to ask the user to allow notification

```
func registerUserNotificationSettings() {
    let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = ([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
  }
```

and after the dialog is displayed and ether user push allow or disallow,

```
didRegister notificationSettings
```

is called. and we call

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications
```

inside it. Which calls

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

and we send the token to our server.

#### 2. Check user has turned off the push permission

After the above and if **use turns off notification form iOS Settings app**, I show a modal alert to ask users to change the notification setting to ON at some point.  I judge to show modal by this code.

```
func isApproved() -> Bool {
    guard let setting = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings else {
      return false
    }
    return setting.types.rawValue > 0
  }
```

We show the modal if isApproved == false.

#### 3. Send user to settings app

On the modal, we placed a button which calls following method

```
func showAppropriateNotificationConfigView() {

    if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications == false {
      // case the app has never called registerUserNotificationSettings or registration failed
      registerUserNotificationSettings()

    } else {
      // registerUserNotificationSettings has beeen called and registration succeed
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
    }
  }
```

Most of our testing device return true (and we confirmed the device token is successfully received) for

```
UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
```

but only one of our device(iPhone7 plus iOS 11.3) returns false. 
So that

```
registerUserNotificationSettings
```

is called and displays nothing instead of sending the user to settings app by

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

### Question

What is wrong with my code and how can we fix it?

I understand some of the methods are deprecated but I need to fix it temporary and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating all related deprecated methods.